# Is it possible to hold a complex data structure inside of a cv::Mat?

Tags: c++, opencv

I have a cv::Mat image, and I am thinking about having a second cv::Mat of the same size, but where each entry stores a complex data structure corresponding to that pixel instead.  Can this be done with cv::Mat or is a vector of vectors my only open there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at [`cv::Mat`](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/documentation/cpp/core_basic_structures.html#mat)'s documentation, especially the constructors and the `type`, `channels` and `depth` methods, it seems to only be able to contain simple OpenCV data types (8/16/32-bit ints, 32/64-bit floats, or 1/2/3/4-tuples of these, but not a mixture, of course).

But even then, I wouldn't suggest a vector of vectors for a two-dimensional array/matrix/image (where all rows have the same number of columns), but rather a simple 1D vector with some simple index magic doing the mapping from 2D to 1D. This has much better memory locality and allocation behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how 'complex' is your data structure. You only may use a structure whose elements have the same type. And opencv offers you this possibility with

```
Vec<n, type>
```

By example

```
Vec<6,float> vv;
//fill vector
vv.push_back(Vec6f(1,2,3,4,5,6);
Mat m(vv);

Vec<6,float> vec = m.at<Vec6f>(1);
```

As christian says, you cannot mix types (have a float channel and a char one)

Comment: And you can of course also not use types other than simple integer or floating point types.